# Change placeholder text after table has loaded. Hence, two values for placeholder text

Tags: tabulator

#### How can I change placeholder text after table has loaded? No jQuery.

Ideal steps:

1. Table loads. No data. Placeholder says: "Fetching data"
2. JSONdata is fetched using:

```
// Script
const getJSON = async url => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if(!response.ok) 
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data; 
    } catch(error) {
        return error;
    }
};
// HTML
var table = new Tabulator("#example", {
    ajaxLoader: false,
    data:JSONdata,
    ...
    ...
}
getJSON('https://...').then(JSONdata => {
            table.replaceData(JSONdata);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
});
```

3. Placeholder text changes to: "No results found."

*P.S. This feature is important when JSON fails or no search results are found. I have added a search function that only shows matched rows.*

Answer (score 0):

```
table.options.placeholder.firstElementChild.textContent = 'No results found.';
```

Probably should be in a `getJSON.then()` block.